# Codeigniter 404 Page Not Found for Sub Domain where WordPress Blog is installed

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working with Codeigniter and WordPress for a website.

Codeigniter installed on the root directory.
WordPress which is used for the blog in the subdomain directory inside the root folder.

Here is the directory structure.

var/www/html/codeigniter  -- Root website here

/var/www/html/codeigniter/blog   -- sub-domain for wordpress blog

here is the .htacess file for Root Directory (var/www/html/codeigniter)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

here is the.htaccess file for the blog directory (/var/www/html/codeigniter/blog)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The subdomain you are trying to access must have a route associated to it in the application/config/routes and it should be pointing towards a valid controller function that returns a valid HTML/JSON data

Comment: I'm not getting the data from WordPress to display on the Codeigniter website. Just need to open the website eg subdomain where WordPress is installed blog but Codeigniter htacess file may be creating an issue.

Comment: have you put the WordPress into the CodeIgniter directory?

Comment: it's solved. My blog directory was not in an accurate place.

Answer (score 0):

it's working. I accidentally put the blog directory into another directory. Moving the blog on subdomain directory is working now.